# Understanding the ActionScript API - can this statement throw an exception?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, exception, actionscript, flash-builder

I want to know whether I should wrap the following statement in a `try catch` block:

```
var newFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);
```

If I look at the API Reference for [resolvePath()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#resolvePath%28%29) and [applicationStorageDirectory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationStorageDirectory), it mentions nothing about throwing exceptions.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: no this does not throw an exception. There nothing that can go wrong, if the file doesn't exist, it still resolves the path to the (non-existant) file. You can afterward try to check if the file exists.

Comment: also, you might want to change `File newfile` to `var newFile:File`

Comment: @Marijn Will this throw an error if the fileName variable is null?  Taht is the only situation I Can think of.  Although this sort of code is not the usual candidate for a try/catch approach.

Comment: I don't think it will throw an error, it will just resolve the path to  applicationStorageDirectory. But you can ofcourse just try it and see if it throws an error :) you could ofcourse check the input (fileName), if it's null or empty, dont resolve the path. Also If you need an exception, you can throw one yourself.

Comment: You should avoid using `try...catch` as often as possible and instead focus on creating error-free code. The `try...catch` block is CPU intensive and depending on hardware, could be a slowdown source if you use it often enough. As for the question at hand, an exception will be thrown if `fileName` is null or if you are not using AIR (though it would be at compile-time in that case). It could also throw an exception if `applicationStorageDirectory` does not exist, but I do not know of an OS where this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried it out. It will throw an error if fileName is null.
-> ArgumentError: Error #2007: Parameter  must be non-null.
But it's better to test if fileName is null before than using a try catch.